# sqlalchemy autoincrement value as foreign key mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, auto-increment, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to use an autoincrementing unique ID field as a foreign key in other tables. My model is below:

```
class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Users'

        uid = Column(INT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        name = Column(TEXT)
        email = Column(TEXT)
        dateRegistered = Column(TIMESTAMP)
        phone = Column(TEXT)

class AddressMap(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'AddressMaps'

        uid = Column(INT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        userId = Column(INT, ForeignKey('Users.uid'))
        addressId = Column(INT, ForeignKey('Addresses.uid'))
        dateCreated = Column(TIMESTAMP)


        user = relationship("User", backref=backref('AddressMaps'))
        address = relationship("Address", backref=backref('AddressMaps'))

class Address(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Addresses'

        uid = Column(INT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        street = Column(TEXT)
        city = Column(TEXT)
        state = Column(TEXT)
        postal = Column(TEXT)
        dateRegistered = Column(TIMESTAMP)
```

My problem is that when I create a user object, it is not created with a uid value. I understand this is because the object has not yet been committed to the database. The problem is that since the User object has None as the uid value, I have no way of linking the AddressMap object with it.

What is the idiomatic way of handling this problem in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need a uid. Since you have created a relationship between the tables, you will be able to add an `AddressMap` object to the user:

```
samantha = User(name='Sam', email='sam@xyz.abc', phone='555-555-5555')
```

You now have access to the `samantha.AddressMaps` collection (see your `backref` under your `user` relationship in your `AddressMap` table). You can add `AddressMap` objects to this collection:

```
samantha.AddressMaps = [AddressMap(dateCreated=datetime.now()),
                        AddressMap(dateCreated=datetime.min)]
```

Now you can add these objects to your `session` and `commit`. See [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects) for more info.

Incidentally, just as an FYI, [you don't need to include `autoincrement=True`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#auto-increment-behavior) on the first integer column of a table.

Comment: This answer saved my life. Thank you man.